# Ordering entities with sortable behavior in Doctrine 2 (Symfony 2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I've created an entity that has a [Sortable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sortable.md) behavior and have one question about using it.
The methods for setting and getting positions are not enough for me, so I want to do simple 
**moveUp** and **moveDown** methods with following code:

```
public function moveUp() {
    ++$this->position;
}

public function moveDown() {
    if($this->position != 0)
        --$this->position;
}
```

With this implementation the **moveUp** method has no limit for incrementing up the item with already max position. *What is the best way to forbid incrementing such items?* I've heard that doing custom queries directly in entities isn't a good practice, so how can I check if the item already has a max value?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, by reading the code I noticed that:

```
// Compute position if it is negative
if ($newPosition < 0) {
    $newPosition += $this->maxPositions[$hash] + 2; // position == -1 => append at end of list
    if ($newPosition < 0) $newPosition = 0;
}
```

(in [SortableListener:141](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Sortable/SortableListener.php#L141))

I guess that by setting `-1` as position, it will be moved to the end of the list. And `-2` will put it second-to-last.

---

**Edit**: Sorry I answered too fast, I also wanted to add:

I don't think you need to limit the position yourself, the `SortableListener` will:

```
// Set position to max position if it is too big
$newPosition = min(array($this->maxPositions[$hash] + 1, $newPosition));
```

So your `moveUp()` function could be (btw did you reverse `moveUp` and `moveDown`?):

```
public function moveUp()
{
    if ($this->position != 0) {
        $this->position--;
    }
}
public function moveDown()
{
    $this->position++;
}
```

---

**Update**: Well after some testing, it turns out there is a bug in that feature.

`setPosition(-1)` will put the object at the end of the list, but it creates a gap in the positions.

I've reproduced it here: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/pull/908

I hope it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

well you can have an event listener hooked which would populate SortableMaxAware interface d entities with a max value fetched from the database. This is of course cumbersome, but hey you are using ORM :) have fun.